# How to make Ansible YAML parsing accept this command?

Tags: yaml, ansible

**Question:**
How to make Ansible YAML parsing accept this command ?

**Details below:**

*This YAML:*

```
-shell: "/home/developer/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository
'http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/update-site' -installIUs
org.moreunit.feature.group"
```

*is validated by:*
http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/
http://www.yamllint.com/
http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

*but ansible says:*

```
This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote.  For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

*As a reference this YAML works perfectly:*

```
-shell: "wget 'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.5.3.tar.gzip'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 - shell: >
      /home/developer/eclipse/eclipse
      -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
      -noSplash
      -repository 'http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/update-site'
      -installIUs org.moreunit.feature.group
```

Do not trust the editor or syntax highlighter. Let ansible tell you if there is a problem (Run it with -C flag to simulate a dry-run if u want). Also try replacing single with double quotes around the repo URL.

Comment: verified on lubuntu 14.04.2, with ansible 1.8.4